# How to deal with the new movies and TV windows 10 app

Tags: video, windows-10

I recently updated to windows 10, and everything went down pretty smoothly for the most part.
However,  the other day while browsing through my movie files (to transfer on my android tablet), I found a whole set of them (mkv) that defaulted to the Movies and TV app that windows 10 offers. They wouldn't open with this app, so I tried right-clicking in order to set default to  VLC. That crashed my documents, and did so on every subsequent try. I remember I had a backup of these files, and on my drive it turned out I could open them (after setting default to VLC, mkv changed to sfv for some reason). I also found out that I could open them through VLC by manually searching the files.

The files on the hard drive of my computer are still derpy, and I can't even so much as drag them that My Documents crashes again. Why would this happen?

I wanna note that before the update all these files were normal, and they were the only ones to have been affected (out of about 100 movies/series).

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  It sounds like the files on your HDD are corrupt.  This is the entire point of a backup.  It is unlikely the upgrade had anything to do with the file corruption.

Comment: @Ramhound my question was if it had anything to do with windows 10, because it happened right after the update